# Linear function of first grade

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, terminology

I have this function:

$f(\bar{x})=c_{0}+\sum_{1}^{n} c_{i}x_{i}$

with $\bar{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Is it correct to call this function : **polynomial function of first grade** ?
And is it correct to call it **hyperplane** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Question: yes, $f$ is a polynomial of grade $1$.
2. Question: No, a hyperplane is a set and not a function.

Comment: Nice. But can i use it to describe an hyperplane ?

Comment: The set $\{\bar{x} \in \mathbb R^n: f(\bar{x})=0\}$ is a hyperplane.

Comment: When I read "grade" I thought "slope", not "degree"/"order". I'd recommend "degree" in English, though I won't claim that no native speaker has used "grade".

Comment: @Mark: thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a polynomial function of degree one but it is not an hyperplane in $R^n$.

It could be an affine hyperplane in $R^{n+1}$

$$c_{0}+\sum_{1}^{n} c_{i}x_{i}=0$$